# Angular 2/4 filter listing on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

My page is split into three components

```
<nav></nav>
<form></form>
<listing></listing>
```

When the page loads it grabs the default data and lists all the items. How do I create a filter, that when you input the text in the form, its filters the items in the listings components and if there is data displays that otherwise error message. I have the form working to grab the search value. But I don't know how to use a pipe to give it the search text and then filter the items in listing. I'm not sure how the form, pipe and listing can all communicate. If there is another easier way to do it, open to that as well. Here is my code.

form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  filter(form: any): void {
    console.log('you submitted value:', form);
    console.log(form.committee)
  }

}
```

form.component.html

```
  <form #filters="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="filter(filters.value)">
  <div class="grid-half">
    <div class="col-md-12 margin-right-sm">
      <div class="input-list">
        <div class="input-unit">
          <label for="tag-name" class="input-label">Tag Name</label>
          <div class="input-control">
            <input type="text" id="tag-name" name="tagname" class="input-element input-element" ngModel>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="panel-buttons">
      <button class="btn btn-gray">Remember Filters</button>
      <button class="btn btn-blue" type="submit">Refresh Results</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

listing.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listings',
  templateUrl: './listings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listings.component.css']
})
export class ListingsComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Array <{}> = []
  length: number

  constructor (private dataService: DataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMockData()
  }

  getMockData(): void {
    this.dataService.getData().then(data =>{
      this.items =  data
      this.length =  data.length
      console.log(this.items)
      console.log(this.length)
    });
  }

}
```

listings.component.html

```
   <table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"><span class="text-blue">ID</span></th>
        <th scope="col bold text-blue"><span class="text-blue">Name</span></th>
        <th scope="col bold text-blue"><span class="text-blue">Owner Committee</span></th>
        <th scope="col bold text-blue"><span class="text-blue">Created By</span></th>
        <th scope="col bold text-blue"><span class="text-blue">Date Created</span></th>
        <th scope="col bold text-blue"><span class="text-blue">Description</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>
          <div class="item-info"><span class="item-name"><a href="javascript:void(0);">{{item.name}}</a></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>{{item.owner}}</td>
        <td>{{item.created}}</td>
        <td>{{item.date}}</td>
        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return []
    if (!searchText) return items
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase()
    return items.filter(it => {
      return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: so what is the issue with this code?

Comment: im not sure how to pass the value im collecting from form in the form compoment to the listing component/pipe to actually filter

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am learning Angular and currently stuck with a similar situation.